# Execute Java on Ubuntu: PHP exec() is not working while console works just fine

Tags: java, php, ubuntu, permissions, exec

My website needs PHP to run a Java program in the background. So, PHP issues `exec()` method to let Java do all the work. The implementation works fine on Windows, but completely failed on Ubuntu. While `exec()` doesn't work, a stand-alone test with console works just fine.

I've setup a `test.php` to narrow down the problem:

```
<?php
$output = exec("java -cp ~/path/to/java/class/file/folder Hello 2>&1");
//$output = exec("whoami");
echo $output;
?>
```

The `Hello.java` is simply:

```
public class Hello {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hello, world!");
   }
}
```

By running `test.php` on localhost, it shows:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Hello
```

I tried to narrow down the cause of the error, and my thought went like this:

1. `exec()` itself is problematic: 
   unlikely, since `whoami` prints out apache-user as expected.
2. what the error message means: 

   I searched about this error. Post like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class) talks about it is caused by the **absence of classpath**. **It's not the case for me** either, because in console it works. So the error message means nothing (does it?)
3. user/group permission:

   Is it possible that apache-user is not permitted to run the class file?
   I checked, and found the permission code of `Hello.class` to be `rw-r--r--`, owned by `apache-user:webmasters`. 
   But, even if no one has `x` permission of the file, in console I can still run it (using my own user). 
   I'm not sure about the situation here. But my understanding is that by running java program, **it is really `JVM` executing it (or something else)**; so the permission of `Hello.class` doesn't matter.



   I found another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467704/cant-execute-java-program-with-php-exec-function) has a similar situation. But its solution - specifying full path to Java bin `/usr/bin/java` - doesn't work for me...

What is causing the error?

Can anyone help? Detailed solution is appreciated! I'm a newbie @_@

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Is the path/to/java file accessible by the apache-user?

Comment: Yes, apache-user is the owner of both the file and the subdirectory, and in the group to the project base dir, which has `r` access at least.

Comment: wait... `ls /path/to/java/class/foldr 2>&1' access denied. Let me try again... My bad!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `java -cp /path/to/folder/containing/class/file Hello 2>&1`? It appears that the class file itself should not be the classpath. It should be *in* the classpath. If this were a .jar file, on the other hand, then you would provide the filename in the classpath.

Comment: Hi Soumya! My bad. In the real path name, it is the directory, not the class file itself. I've edited my question to reflect that. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

Give the path and Hello.java file free.

Test the rights for the apache user with:

```
sudo -u webmasters java -cp /path/to/java/class/file/folder Hello

chmod a+r Hello.class
```

Comment: Hi Joop! When I run the first line, it says "sudo: echo.php: command not found". Besides, what is the "echo.php"?

Comment: Erred; should have been "java ..."

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem... It's quite unexpected.

I changed the classpath.

Previously it's something like `~/myproject/to/java/class/file/folder`. 
And I changed it to `/home/myuser/myproject/to/java/class/file/folder`.

But I completely don't understand why `~` notation doesn't work with `exec()`.

Comment: ~ Is referring the current users home directory. So when running the script under apache the current user is in your case apache-user. So when you execute php exec() using the ~ it would be most likely pointing to /home/apache-user/. Which from your own answer is not were the script is located.

Comment: `~` doesn't work because it's a _"placeholder"_ for the home directory of the current user. 1 of 3 things is wrong: the home directory of apache user isn't the one you want. 2: you're running in safe mode, and the `~` is being escaped (not sure if PHP escapes tildes, but could be) _or_ you're relying on a given .profile file to be loaded, which `exec` doesn't do either (probably irrelevant here)

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks guys!